# Jquery toggle messes with the alignment of bootstrap card filtering

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have written a jquery function to perform bootstrap card search operation and it works fine. But the search result is not displaying properly. I need to sort the cards as a normal search operation. But the results are displayed in the order in which they were displayed before.

Using toggle makes the card display to none so the alignment issue is sorted! right? But it is not working.

The data is binded to the cards.

> binding data function

```
 public string BindCard_AssetReport(string main_group, string sub_group, string deptmnt, string empId)
{
    string ddlGroup = DDLAssetGroup.SelectedItem.Text;
    string ddlSubGrp = DDLAssetSubGroup.SelectedItem.Text;
    string ddlDept = DDLDepartment.SelectedItem.Text;
    string ddlUserCode = DDLUser.SelectedItem.Value;


    DataTable dtAsset = getAssetReportList(ddlGroup, ddlSubGrp, ddlDept, ddlUserCode, Session["firmcode"].ToString(), Session["ConnStr"].ToString());



    string str = "<div class='col-md-12'>";
    for (int i = 0; i < dtAsset.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        str = str + "<div class='card-deck'>";
        str = str + "<div class='col-md-3'>";
        str = str + "<div class='card text-white bg-danger'>";
        str = str + "<div class='card-header text-center font-weight-bold'>" + "Code : ".ToString() + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() + " </div> ";
        str = str + " <div class='card-body'>";
        str = str + "<h5 class='card-title text-center font-weight-bold'>" + "Name : ".ToString() + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " </h5> ";
        str = str + "<ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>";
        str = str + "<li class='list-group-item list-group-flush'>  Group : " + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() + "</li>";
        str = str + "<li class='list-group-item list-group-flush'> Sub-Group : " + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString() + "</li>";
        str = str + "<li class='list-group-item list-group-flush'> Department : " + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString() + "</li>";
        str = str + "<li class='list-group-item list-group-flush'> Model : " + dtAsset.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString() + "</li>";
        str = str + "</ul>";
        str = str + "</div>";
        str = str + "</div>";
        str = str + "</div>";
        str = str + "</div>";

    }
    str = str + "</div>";

    return str;
}
```

> where cards are displayed

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblasset" <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="search" placeholder="Start typing.." id="searchinput" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search" class="form-control searchbox-input pull-left" >
                        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body clearfix ">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="cardDiv">
                            <div id="div_list" runat="server">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

> Jquery function

```
 $("#searchinput").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#cardDiv .card").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).find('.card-body').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
```

I have attched the screenshots of my issue. I am a beginner.Please. I need all the help i can get.

[image: Original view]
[image: Messed up View]
[image: Messed-up view 2]

I need to do a proper search function. Since I have a low reputation on stack overflow. I usually don't get many replies. Looking for all the help I can get.
Thank You

Comment: please create a code snippet or add a jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle link. Card format is not correctly shown in the fiddle. It is working properly in fiddle. But when using cards it's not working. Maybe it's my fault. I am using jsfiidle for the first time. You can see it in my screenshots. Here is my link  https://jsfiddle.net/lothbrock/pztw1cny/4/

Comment: @XenioGracias If you look at my screenshots you will understand my issue. In Jsfiddle card view is not working. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using??

Comment: Bootstrap 4 @XenioGracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in your jquery `$("#cardDiv .card")` you were hiding the `.card` div but the div with `.col-md-3` was present on the screen you have to hide that div
changed `$("#cardDiv .col-md-3").filter(function()`. hope it helps you. below is the js fiddle link. thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/ompavcxz/`444`

```js
$("#searchinput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#cardDiv .col-md-3").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).find('.card-body').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input type="search" placeholder="Start typing.." id="searchinput" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="search" class="form-control searchbox-input pull-left">

<div class="panel-body clearfix ">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="cardDiv">
    <div id="div_list" runat="server">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-101</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-102</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-103</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-104</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-105</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-106</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-107</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-108</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-109</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-danger" style="display: block;">
            <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold">Code : AS00012 </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Name : noel </h5>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Group : MRI</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Sub-Group : machine</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Department : Ortho</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-flush"> Model : bst-110</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```